# Multiple BindIp in MongoDB 3.4.1 on Debian Jessie

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I just upgraded from MongoDB 3.2 to 3.4.1.

/etc/mongod.conf had a multiple BindIP:

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,192.168.20.1]
```

This is not working anymore.
I get this error :

```
Scalar option 'net.bindIp' must be a single value
```

According to the documentation, It must be correct :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIP

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove []. so solution is: `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.20.1` and remember, no space characters anywhere in that string.

Comment: I tried but there was a space between the ips... Thanks !