# Assigning multiple IP addresses to MongoDB 7.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, linux, ubuntu

**The Problem**

I am trying but failing, in MongoDB 7.0, on Ubuntu, to bind multiple IP addresses to `net.bindIp` in `mongod.conf`

**What I have tried**

I have tried `127.0.0.1,x.x.x.x`, `127.0.0.1;x.x.x.x`, `[127.0.0.1,x.x.x.x]`, `[127.0.0.1;x.x.x.x]` and `mongod` fails to start on each and everyone.

when the syntax is

`[127.0.0.1,x.x.x.x]`
I get this error

```
Aug 22 11:52:36 ip-172-26-1-93 mongod[41708]: Scalar option 'net.bindIp' must be a single value
```

and when I use any other syntax, I get this error

```
Aug 22 11:54:38 ip-172-26-1-93 mongod[41723]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-22T11:54:38.935Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"main","msg":"Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"}
```

**Where I have looked**

After searching this extensively, I found
[this answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191464/255442)
and
[the answers to this question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192757/how-to-set-mongod-config-set-multiple-bindip-addresses)
and after tryin their solutions I still get the same errors.

I have looked at the documentation for the latest version and I can't see where I am going wrong.

**Additional**

I can successfully bind `0.0.0.0`, however this then defeats the object of using `net.bindIp`

**Edit**

1. I have tried reinstalling MongoDB 3 times now, and still the same issue

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)?

Comment: @mustaccio yes I have. I have tried every possible variation of the [] / [x,x] / [x;x] and x,x / x;x / x, x syntax and I either get 'scalar option 'net.bindIp must be a single value' or it fails to start the daemon. I have edited the question to say I have also tried reinstalling the MongoDB instance.

Comment: I haven't test with latest versions, but earlier versions there was "feature" that if there was even one space character in that bindIp, it failed. 192.168.2.29,127.0.0.1

Comment: yes, I have tried all possible variations of the syntax with spaces and without spaces

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit in particular which line?

Comment: The interfaces and their IP's

Comment: rob@ip-172-26-1-93:~$ ifconfig
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.26.1.93  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.26.15.255

BUT thats not the IP address that I have assigned to my DNS. Im using AWS Lightsail if its any help.

Comment: So, you have only one interface. In this case `net.bindIpAll: true` will do exactly the same. What do you mean by "assigned to my DNS"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit oh my bad I was reading it totally wrong. Okay sure thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bindIP should be the ip address or hostname of **the** host. The mongod cannot bind an ip addrress of another host. This should be the relevant section on each host.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/socketexception-cannot-assign-requested-address/10964

In most cases, you can use localhost, 127.0.0.1, and the server name.
Otherwise, just 0.0.0.0 for all the IP or hostnames that are assigned to the host server if the server has multi IP addresses or multi hostnames.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is no reason to assign multiple IP-Addresses. This makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces. However, since MongoDB does not support multiple network interfaces, it would be pointless anyway.

Either use `net.bindIpAll: true` if you like to permit connections from remote machines or use `net.bindIp: localhost` if you need to permit connections only from the local machine.

Anything else does not make much sense.